# int.TryParse overwrites the value of the integer passed as an out parameter

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, .net-4.0

I have this code...

```
var i = int.MinValue;
var s = string.Empty;
int.TryParse(s, out i);
```

After the `TryParse` Statement, the value in the `i` variable is overwritten (`as zero`) and my previous value is lost.

Is this a bug? If No, is there any implementation detail as to why that was necessary to re-initialize the variable passed as an `out` parameter

Comment: You don't need to initialize i,  replace the first line with `int i;` and the code should still work.

Comment: What happens when i give var i=100; int.TryParse("012",out i); ? Is a need to assign value to i ? explain

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The entire point of `out` is that it *guarantees* (well, at the C# level at least... not the IL level) to overwrite this value. The purpose of this is to **avoid unnecessary assignments**, while allowing "definite assignment". For example:

```
int i; // note: not assigned
var s = string.Empty;

// here "i" is not "definitely assigned"
int.TryParse(s, out i);
// here "i" is "definitely assigned"
```

The idea is that you use the return value, for example:

```
if(int.TryParse(s, out i)) {
   // here "i" makes sense; feel free to use it
} else {
   // here you shouldn't use the value of "i"
}
```

In your specific case, you could re-order:

```
if(!int.TryParse(s, out i)) i = int.MinValue;
```

In particular, note that (in C#, at least) the method **must** assign the value, and **cannot** use the incoming value; for example:

```
static void Foo(out int i) {
    return; // error: hasn't assigned to i
}
static void Bar(out int i) {
    int j = i; // error: cannot read from "i" until Bar has assigned a value
    i = j;
}
static void Baz(out int i) {
    i = 0; // note that after this assignment, code in Baz can read from "i"
}
```

---

Contrast to `ref`; when passing `ref` value, it is **required** to be definitely assigned at the caller. The method itself *may or may not* look at the incoming value (as it chooses), and *may or may not* assign a new value (as it chooses). For example:

```
int i;
SomeMethod(ref i); // illegal - "i" is not definitely assigned

int i = 0;
SomeMethod(ref i); // legal
```

and:

```
static void Foo(ref int i) {
    return; // perfectly legal to not look at "i" and/or not assign "i"
}
static void Foo(ref int i) {
    i = i + 1; // perfectly legal to look at "i" and/or assign "i"
}
```

Comment: I am going to select your response as an answer because of the clear explanation of the question and the examples with usages of out. Please add a comparison for `ref` in your answer as well, because I think if the variable was passed as a `ref` parameter than it was expecting to be initialized...

Answer (score 5):

This isn't a bug, zero is being returned if the conversion fails. the return value of the function in this case will be false.

> When this method returns, contains the 32-bit signed integer value
>   equivalent to the number contained in s, if the conversion succeeded,
>   or zero if the conversion failed. The conversion fails if the s
>   parameter is null, is not of the correct format, or represents a
>   number less than MinValue or greater than MaxValue. This parameter is
>   passed uninitialized.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx

Answer (score 2):

[**out (C# Reference)**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3c3bfhx%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

> Although variables passed as an out arguments need not be initialized
>   prior to being passed, the **calling method is required to assign a
>   value before the method returns**.

[`Int32.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx) initializes it with `default(int)` which is zero.

When this method returns, contains the 32-bit signed integer value equivalent to the number contained in `s`, if the conversion succeeded, **or zero if the conversion failed**.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a bug because it is an out parameter. As an exercise, try writing C# that doesn't set the value of an out parameter. (Hint: It's impossible) Therefore the outcome you observe is the only logical one - the out variable isn't "re-initialized", it's just plain initialized.

If TryParse had been written to take a ref int then what you want would have been possible. Personally I think out int is better here.

Answer (score 0):

No it is not a bug if you will set to variable s value for example "3"

```
var s = "3";
```

you will get value of i will be equal to 3

if you set string.Empty it will be zero it is default implementation

you can take a look on decompiled implementation code

```
internal static unsafe bool TryParseInt32(string s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info, out int result)
{
  byte* stackBuffer = stackalloc byte[114];
  Number.NumberBuffer number = new Number.NumberBuffer(stackBuffer);
  result = 0;
  if (!Number.TryStringToNumber(s, style, ref number, info, false))
    return false;
  if ((style & NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier) != NumberStyles.None)
  {
    if (!Number.HexNumberToInt32(ref number, ref result))
      return false;
  }
  else if (!Number.NumberToInt32(ref number, ref result))
    return false;
  return true;
}
```

result is set to 0;